# How do I install Droid Explorer?

Tags: droid-explorer

I downloaded this droidexplorer-master zip from some github or something site because the droidexplorer site said to go there for latest updated version... now how do I install it? I can't seem to locate any setup.exe...
I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: 1) Please make clear the question's relationship with Android; 2) the suffix `-master.zip` means you downloaded a package of the source tree, which needs to be compiled locally. If that's not what you want, look for a compiled version elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

zip files are usually* installed using a custom recovery. Go search for TWRP or CWM for your device. *To be sure, we need to know the content of the zip file.

But I don't think this is what you want. You should search for droidexplorer on Google Play or other markets.

Answer (score 0):

From the instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Jonatino/Droid-Explorer), "Make sure you have Java 1.8 u40 or higher. Double click the run.bat to build the project. Once the build is finished, press any key to open Droid-Explorer."